# Компиляция программы на Rust через Clang

Tags: rust, clang

Скомпилируется ли программа написанная на Rust через Clang?

Comment: Clang - это компилятор для языков C и C++. Не очень понятно, при чём тут Rust...

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не скомпилируется. Clang умеет компилировать С, С++, Objective C, CUDA, OpenCL.

Answer (score -1):

Программы на rust компилируются и собираются исключительно через Cargo.

Comment: Это неправда, при желании можно вызывать rustc напрямую без Cargo (и об этом рассказывается в [первой же главе книги](https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch01-02-hello-world.html))

Comment: Если со строгой академической точки зрения, вынужден с Вами согласиться... Но с практической точки зрения -- только Cargo. К тому же, это и ещё и менеджер пакетов, а без них вообще никак.